# What is the return type of a router function?

Tags: node.js, express

If I want to avoid lots of `else` blocks and deep indentations, what should be the return type if I want to exit a router function explictly?

```
app.get("/xx", function(req, res) {
   if (c1) {
      res.render("c1");
      return ??;
   }
   if (c2) {
      res.render("c2");
      return ??;
   }
   res.render("default");
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't really matter. This is an asynchronous function, and nobody's going to use this return value, so you can just return `undefined`:

```
res.render(...);
return;
```

As it doesn't matter, you can also write:

```
return res.render(...);
```

But I think it looks more readable in two lines.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `res.render()` you should be using `res.send()`, as it will terminate the response stream with the output sent.

Comment: or just add 'return res.send()'

Comment: @UditKumawat, is `return res.render("xx")` also ok?

Comment: There's no need for `send`, as `res.render()` also sends the rendered output. See [documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.render)

Comment: @OldGeezer, it's also OK, because, as I've mentioned in my answer, it doesn't really matter what you're returning.